# xml.etree.ElementTree root.findall not returning all

Tags: python

python --version:
Python 2.7.5

I have this script to parse junit xml file and addup all test errors.

I am trying to use root.findall(".//*[@errors]") but it is only finding first **testsuite** instead of all.

I am getting:

```
('tests: ', '16')
('issues: ', '0')
```

but I am expecting:

```
('tests: ', '37')
('issues: ', '5')
```

Appreciate your help.

script:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),filename)  
 

print("Processing File: ", format(filepath))
    
tests = 0
failures = 0
errors = 0
skipped = 0
issues = 0

file = open(filepath, "r")

tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

tests += int(root.findall(".//*[@tests]")[0].attrib.get("tests"))
failures += int(root.findall(".//*[@failures]")[0].attrib.get("failures"))
errors += int(root.findall(".//*[@errors]")[0].attrib.get("errors"))
skipped += int(root.findall(".//*[@skipped]")[0].attrib.get("skipped"))

issues += int(failures) + int(errors)
status = "PASSED"
        
if issues > 0:
    status = "FAILED"

print("tests: ", format(tests))
print("issues: ", format(issues))
print("status: ", format(status))
sys.exit(issues)
```

Input xml file:

```
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="TestVal" tests="16" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="0" timestamp="1976-01-01T15:53:31" hostname=" " time="0"> 
<properties/> 
</testsuite> 
<testsuite name="TestSmoke" tests="1" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="1" timestamp="1976-01-01T15:53:31" hostname=" " time="0"> 
<properties/> 
</testsuite> 
<testsuite errors="4" failures="0" hostname="abc" name="testui" skipped="2" tests="20" time="39.128" timestamp="2021-09-28T13:27:31.243701"></testsuite></testsuites>
```

Comment: As an aside, its odd that you require the xml to be in the same directory as your script (`filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),filename)`). Usually you don't want to mix your code and your data.

Comment: I am have simplified it for this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you find all of the elements, and then just use the first one. Simplifying your example to just one of the attributes, you can use a generator with the `sum` function to add them all up. I've included an example with a for loop to show the exploded view.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filepath = "test.xml"

file = open(filepath, "r")
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()
# you could handle each elem separately...
#tests = 0
#for elem in root.findall(".//*[@tests]"):
#    tests += int(elem.attrib.get("tests"))
# ... or just sum them up
tests = sum(int(elem.attrib.get("tests")) for elem in root.findall(".//*[@tests]"))
print("tests: ", format(tests))
```